# retrieving HTTP Post request from JobAdder

Tags: php, wordpress, http-post

I have been tasked with linking jobs on Jobadder to my clients WP site.

Jobadder cannot use SFTP which was my preferred option, so plan b is to HTTP POST the XML data to the website.

They asked for a URL so i did some research and found that WP has inbuilt functions for this.

So here is my code in the functions.php file of the theme

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
 register_rest_route( 'xmlfeed/v1', '/jobs', array(
 'methods'  => 'POST',
 'callback' => 'get_jobs',
 ) );
} );

function get_jobs() {
 header('Content-type: text/xml');
 if ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' ) {
    $data = file_get_contents("php://input");
    $xmlfile = "jobs.xml";
    $FileHandle = fopen($xmlfile, "w") or die("can't open file");
    fwrite( $FileHandle, str_replace("xml=", "", urldecode($data)) );
    fclose($FileHandle);
}
```

So, when i go to http://xxx.staging.wpengine.com/wp-json/xmlfeed/v1/jobs in Postman, and add some XML data to the body it displays back.

However, it does not seem to fire the code to write to an XML file.

I have never done this before and have not found anything on the web to help, so hoping some one can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

worked it out - needed the full path to the XML file, in this case - "wp-content/uploads/job-feed/jobs.xml"